# Regex to replace substring only if the word does not contain a specefic substring

Tags: regex

I want to replace org in word but only if it does not contains the substring gross.
For ex

```
org_selling -> original_selling
```

but

```
org_selling_gross -> org_selling_gross
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that the following logic works:

```
Find:    org_(?!\w*gross)
Replace: original_
```

The regex find pattern says to match:

- `org_`
- `(?!\w*gross)` assert that "gross" does NOT appear in following substring

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8h3qt/1).